How to check in kdb+ if a connection opened to current process is using TLS
I have a situation where I want users to connect using TLS, but I want my kdb procs to also permit plain connection so a -E 1 is specified on the proc.
The problem is, I want to enforce users to use TLS to connect to my app, but I don't know how I can check to see if a connection has been opened using TLS.
For example, when someone uses the InteliJ plugin to connect to my kdb proc I want to check if the user is an LDAP user (I have this specified in a csv config) an then I want to check if the connection is using TLS. If user is LDAP, but no TLS, reject connection.
I know that if a connection comes from a kdb proc, I can use .z.e.
Is this even possible?
If it is not possible, does this mean I will have to use a 2-way verification in which client verifies server certs and server verify client certs?

I don't know if there's a simple way to tell for a non-q connection. My only thought was to have two process - one running -E 2 /TLS only and one running -E 0 /plain - and then have a gateway/loadbalancer process sitting on top of both which has -E 1 / plain & TLS.
Your gateway/loadbalancer can determine from the incoming connections (-38! might help here too as well as .z.e) if it's a q process or a non-q process requesting. If it's a q process sending the request route it to the -E 0 server and if it's non-q route it to the -E 2 server.
Some gateway/loadbalancer docs:
https://code.kx.com/q/kb/load-balancing/
https://code.kx.com/q/wp/gateway-design/
https://code.kx.com/q/wp/query-routing/
